# Pull data from google plus profile

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I want to pull a users's `posts` from his/her `google+` profile.

I created a project in https://console.developers.google.com/

And got a `Project ID: xyz Project Number: 58xxxxxxxx17`

Now how can i make a system where a user will `sign-in` with `google+` and I will get `his/her` posts.

I have read the `api` documentation. But can anyone show any example code or links from where I can achieve what I want?

**UPDATE**

Cant fetch the users' activities!!

```
//apid = my client_id
//user_id = id of user
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"+userid+"/activities/public?key="+apid
        })
        .done(function( data ){
            console.log(data);
        });
```

console gets this error

```
         GET 
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/106585xxxxxx000/activities/…y=5871xx312xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com 
    400 (Bad Request)jquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 

    x.ajaxTransport.x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.sendjquery-2.0.3.min.js:6 
    x.extend.ajaxhome.php:788 signinCallbackcb=gapi.loaded_0:355 

    _.k.iucb=gapi.loaded_0:493 ixcb=gapi.loaded_0:499 (anonymous function)cb=gapi.loaded_0:44 h.pu._.C.h.vEcb=gapi.loaded_0:47 

    Wqcb=gapi.loaded_0:47 _.C.yecb=gapi.loaded_0:42 Ap
```

Comment: start with looking up Oauth2 you will need it to authenticate you wont need the project id for anything.  you will need a client id.

Comment: I did em and was able to sign-in  but how do i get the `posts` of that signed-in user @DaImTo ???

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list

Comment: @DaImTo cant do see update

Comment: you cant update or post to the Google+ timeline of a user with the Google+ api.

Comment: Lol ! i mean see update of my question @DaImTo

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to get user's public posts with their GOOGLE PLUS ID with sign-in

**Note that:**
You should have **Client ID** and which can be generated by following the steps in 
[Link1](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingoauth2) and [Link2](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/)

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Google+ Sign-in button demo: rendering with JavaScript</title>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" 
type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var loginFinished = function(authResult)
{  
var token = authResult.access_token; 
gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function()
{                           
 //To get the public posts of his/her using their GOOGLEPLUSID               
 window.open("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/GOOGLEPLUSID/activities/public?alt=json&access_token="+token+"&maxResults=100");

//if you dont know the GOOGLEPLUSID of his/her you can get GOOGLEPLUSID by calling below API with their details(query) in the result 'id' field gives GOOGLEPLUSID

window.open("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people?query=Robert Smith+Alamosa&alt=json&maxResults=20&access_token="+token); 

 });  

//OR to see the Public Posts result in console

var request =   gapi.client.request({'path':'/plus/v1/people/GOOGLEPLUSID/activities/public'});
 request.execute(function(resp) {                                       
         console.log(resp);                                                
 });

 };

var options = {
'callback': loginFinished,
'approvalprompt': 'force',
'clientid': 'ENTER YOUR CLIENT ID HERE',
'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',
'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
};

var renderBtn = function()
{
 gapi.signin.render('renderMe', options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload ="renderBtn()">
<div id="renderMe"></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No ! `gapi not defined `

Comment: Have you included `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>` ??

Comment: this one `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>` @manjunathH

Comment: yes Slim Shady. even I used `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>` and tested it worked fine. If I didn't include this script than it showing `gapi is not defined` for me in console.